# Suma de valores en un json

Tags: php, sql-server

por favor necesito sumar una fila de valores de un json:

```
public function getRealCobranza2() {
$response = array();
$serverName = "xxxxxx";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
if( $conn === false )  
{  
    echo "Could not connect.\n";  
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  
$anio = date("YY");
$mes = date("MM"); 
/* Define the query. */  
$tsql = "exec sp_AnalisisCobranza_Presupuesto 2020,2,10";    
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array($codigo_vendedor));  
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $response[] = array(
        'vendedor' => utf8_encode($row['Vendedor']),
        'nombre_cliente' => utf8_encode($row['CardName']),
        'supervisor' => utf8_encode($row['Supervisor']),
        'saldo' => ($row['Saldo']),
        'efectivo' => utf8_encode($row['Efectivo']),
        'transferencia' => utf8_encode($row['Transferencia']),
        'retencion' => utf8_encode($row['Retencion']),
        'cheque' => utf8_encode($row['Cheque']),
        'reconciliacion' => utf8_encode($row['Reconciliacion']),
        'fechaPresupuesto' => ($row['FechaPresupuesto']),
        'fechaVencimiento' => ($row['FechaVence']),
        'suma_efectivo' => ''
    ); 
}  
$total_efectivo = 0;
     $total_transferencia = 0;
     $total_retencion = 0;
     $total_cheque = 0;
     $total_reconciliacion = 0;
     $real = 0;
     foreach($response as $key){
         $total_efectivo = $total_efectivo + $key["efectivo"];      
         $total_transferencia = $total_transferencia + $key["transferencia"];      
         $total_retencion = $total_retencion + $key["retencion"];      
         $total_cheque = $total_cheque + $key["cheque"];      
         $total_reconciliacion = $total_efectivo + $key["reconciliacion"];       
     }  
    
     $total_reconciliacion;  
     $real = $total_efectivo + $total_transferencia + $total_retencion + 
     $total_cheque + $total_reconciliacion;
     $response["real"] = $real;
     return round(($response["real"]),2);
/* Free statement and connection resources. */  
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
}
```

Mi json es el siguiente:

"error": false,
"real": [
{
"vendedor": "Jose Luis Mateo",
"nombre_cliente": "ALBAN TORRES JOSE ENRIQUE",
"supervisor": "Pedro Loor",
"saldo": "36.780000",
"efectivo": ".000000",
"transferencia": ".000000",
"retencion": ".000000",
"cheque": "36.780000",
"reconciliacion": ".000000",
"fechaPresupuesto": {
"date": "2020-02-01 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "UTC"
},
"fechaVencimiento": {
"date": "2020-02-23 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "UTC"
}
},
{
"vendedor": "Jose Luis Mateo",
"nombre_cliente": "ALBAN TORRES JOSE ENRIQUE",
"supervisor": "Pedro Loor",
"saldo": "409.750000",
"efectivo": ".000000",
"transferencia": ".000000",
"retencion": ".000000",
"cheque": "409.750000",
"reconciliacion": ".000000",
"fechaPresupuesto": {
"date": "2020-02-01 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "UTC"
},
"fechaVencimiento": {
"date": "2020-02-09 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "UTC"
}
}

Necesito obtener un json que solo me devuelva el resultado de la suma de efectivo, transferencia, retencion, cheque y reconciliacion. Intente hacer un
foreach y si me funciona pero no creo que sea lo mejor para sumar valores de una propiedad de un json, por ejemplo, tengo el campo efectivo, y quisiera sumar
toda su fila y posteriormente ese resultado sumarlo con transferencia, retencion,
cheque y reconciliacion.

Comment: ¿Por qué sumar desde el JSON? Puedes hacer las operaciones al recorrer los datos. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado y, de ser necesario, una explicación más detallada.

Comment: Hola, he editado mi pregunta, por favor si me puedes apoyar te lo agradeceria muchisimo, puse lo que habia intentado y lo que trato de hacer

Comment: un json es un string con un formato particular, que te hace pensar que una libreria no va a hacer exactamente lo mismo que vos para llegar al resultado que vos ya lograste????

Comment: Es que no deseo ninguna libreria, sino una forma optimizada debido a que este resultado lo usare en calculos posteriores y se hara muy lenta la consulta por muchos procesos por detras. Entonces esa era mi inquietud.